# Couple algorithms for user-input strings

Tags: c++, string, user-input

First of all i am new to coding and stackoverflow if i have obvious mistakes that i miss please forgive me.

Hello, i am writing c++ code and i need to get sentence from user and do a couple things with it.

1. How many letter does your string have?
2. How many words does your string have?

I am getting string with this code :

```
string str;
cout << "Please enter your string."<<endl;
getline(cin,str);
cout<< "Your string is : "<<a<<endl;
cout<<"Length of your string is : "<<str.length();
```

I am getting the length of string with `str.length` but it counts the spaces too my question is, how i determine the "space"?

Comment: Try to use the `std::string::find` method :-)

Comment: Look up how to use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) to count letters from the string (if they mean as opposed to numbers, special characters, etc)

Comment: You can count the number of non-space characters with a simple `std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [] ( const char c ) { return !std::isspace(c); });`. Variations of this algorithm will let you find and possibly "tokenize" your string according to this predicate. You can even add other non-space characters to the lambda that you want to skip over

Comment: You might find this reference of use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Comment: I am going to check those methods right now thank you :)

Comment: @KABoissonneault Oh i see this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i dont have enough of reputations to post a comment,i am writing down here:

Though @KABoissonneault is perfectly correct,but i would suggest giving a look at strtok too.
strtok can tokenize your string based on any delimiter(space being your case)